# Creating a simple, basic page object in Nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js, pageobjects

Ok, so I've read up on the use of page_objects in **nightwatch.js**, but I'm still getting issues with it (which I'm convinced is due to something obvious and/or simple).

Using http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#page-objects as the guide, I added the the file **cookieremoval.js** in my **page_objects** folder.

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {
    removeCookies: {
    selector: '.banner_continue--2NyXA'
    }
  }
}
```

In my **nightwatch.conf.js** file I have;

```
page_objects_path: "tests/functional/config/page_objects",
```

And in my **test script** I have;

```
module.exports = {
  "/cars/road-tax redirects to /car-tax/ ": browser => {
  browser.url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carReviews)
    .assert.urlEquals(browser.launchUrl + "/car-reviews/") 
    .waitForElementPresent('@cookieRemove', 3000)
    .click('@cookieRemove')
  .end(); 
  },
};
```

However, when I run the test, I keep getting an error reading;

```
Timed out while waiting for element <@cookieRemove>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you never instantiated your page object.  You're asking the browser object to search for an unknown element, that's why it's timing out.  Your code should look something like this in your test script: `var cookieRemoval = browser.page.cookieremoval();` then use this object to access those variables and functions in your page object.  For example, if you wanted to access the remove cookie element, then you would do this `cookieRemoval.click('@removeCookies');`.

Secondly, you will have to know when to use the global `browser` object and when to use your page object.  If you need to access something within your page object, obviously use the page object to call a function or access a variable.  Otherwise, `browser` won't know the element you're looking for exists.  Hope this help you out, I would definitely spend some more time learning about objects and specifically how they're used in nightwatch.js.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Many thanks for your help Wayne K and your prompt response. I will indeed spend some time reading and understanding page objects for nightwatch.js as I envisage using them on a regular basis. Thanks again.